# Segmentation fault with vector< vector<bool>> &

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault, boolean

I am having problems when i try to get the selected values in a knapsack problem variant. To be specific. I get the error
`Segmentation fault (core dumped)` 
in the line `if(traza[n][w]`

This is my code:

```
void getSelection(vector<double> &ws, vector<vector<bool>> &traza, vector<bool> &sol){
    unsigned nobjects = traza.size()-1;
    int w = traza[0].size()-1;

    for(int n=nobjects;n>0; n--){
        if(traza[n][w]){
            cerr << "basura" << endl;
            sol[n-1]=true;
            w-=ws[n-1];
        }
        else{
            sol[n-1]=false;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the debugger output:

```
(gdb) r -f 2.problem 
Starting program: /home/antonio/Escritorio/ADA/Prac6/maxsum -f 2.problem

Breakpoint 1, getSelection (ws=std::vector of length 10, capacity 16 = {...}, 
    traza=std::vector of length 11, capacity 11 = {...}, 
    sol=std::vector<bool> of length 0, capacity 0) at maxsum.cc:183
183             if(traza[n][w]){
(gdb) s
std::vector<bool, std::allocator<bool> >::operator[] (this=<optimized out>, 
    __n=<optimized out>) at maxsum.cc:183
183             if(traza[n][w]){
(gdb) s
std::_Bit_iterator::operator* (this=<optimized out>, this=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_bvector.h:231
231         { return reference(_M_p, 1UL << _M_offset); }
(gdb) s
std::vector<bool, std::allocator<bool> >::operator[] (this=<optimized out>, 
    __n=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_bvector.h:859
859                            + __n / int(_S_word_bit), __n % int(_S_word_bit));
(gdb) s
std::_Bit_iterator::operator* (this=<optimized out>, this=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_bvector.h:231
231         { return reference(_M_p, 1UL << _M_offset); }
(gdb) s
getSelection (ws=std::vector of length 10, capacity 16 = {...}, 
    traza=std::vector of length 11, capacity 11 = {...}, 
    sol=std::vector<bool> of length 0, capacity 0) at maxsum.cc:183
183             if(traza[n][w]){
(gdb) s
189                 sol[n-1]=false;
(gdb) s
std::vector<bool, std::allocator<bool> >::operator[] (this=<optimized out>, 
    __n=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_bvector.h:859
859                            + __n / int(_S_word_bit), __n % int(_S_word_bit));
(gdb) s
858           return *iterator(this->_M_impl._M_start._M_p
(gdb) s
859                            + __n / int(_S_word_bit), __n % int(_S_word_bit));
(gdb) s
std::_Bit_iterator::operator* (this=<optimized out>, this=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_bvector.h:231
231         { return reference(_M_p, 1UL << _M_offset); }
(gdb) s
std::vector<bool, std::allocator<bool> >::operator[] (this=<optimized out>, 
    __n=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_bvector.h:859
859                            + __n / int(_S_word_bit), __n % int(_S_word_bit));
(gdb) s
getSelection (ws=std::vector of length 10, capacity 16 = {...}, 
    traza=std::vector of length 11, capacity 11 = {...}, 
    sol=std::vector<bool> of length 0, capacity 0) at maxsum.cc:189
189                 sol[n-1]=false;
(gdb) s
std::vector<bool, std::allocator<bool> >::operator[] (this=0x7ffffffedce0, 
    __n=<optimized out>) at maxsum.cc:189
189                 sol[n-1]=false;
(gdb) s
std::_Bit_iterator::operator* (this=<optimized out>, this=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_bvector.h:231
231         { return reference(_M_p, 1UL << _M_offset); }
(gdb) s
std::vector<bool, std::allocator<bool> >::operator[] (this=0x7ffffffedce0, 
    __n=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_bvector.h:859
859                            + __n / int(_S_word_bit), __n % int(_S_word_bit));
(gdb) s
getSelection (ws=std::vector of length 10, capacity 16 = {...}, 
    traza=std::vector of length 11, capacity 11 = {...}, 
    sol=std::vector<bool> of length 0, capacity 0) at maxsum.cc:189
189                 sol[n-1]=false;
(gdb) s
std::_Bit_reference::operator= (__x=false, this=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_bvector.h:89
89              *_M_p &= ~_M_mask;
(gdb) s

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000008004e46 in std::_Bit_reference::operator= (__x=false, this=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_bvector.h:89
89              *_M_p &= ~_M_mask;
(gdb) s

Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
The program no longer exists.
(gdb)
```

I have read that boolean vector in c++ are a bit weird. I don't understand why I cannnot reference a specific element in this kind of vector. Thank you very much:

Comment: `int w = traza[0].size()-1;` Your loop starts from `n`, not `0`.

Comment: @IAntonio Bri Your code is unsafe. You are not checking whether vectors have the required number of elements. Even the first statement of the function unsigned nobjects = traza.size()-1; can invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: If `traza[0].size()` is zero, `w = traza[0].size()-1` gives a large positive value since `size()` returns an unsigned type.  For example, the value will be `4294967296` if the type returned by `size()` is a 32-bit unsigned type.  Using that as an index, as in `traza[n][w]` gives undefined behaviour, unless `traza[n].size()` is that value or more.

Comment: it seems that sol is empty...`sol is empty `sol=std::vector<bool> of length 0, capacity 0)`

Comment: @bertubezz That was the problem!! I did not initialize the vector '-.-. Thank you!